# Switch classes from controller and renew view in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a popup window with several tabs in my angular application.
The tabs have bootstrap-like styles and I should switch them via angular.
I have the following markup for my tabs (the code is simplified):

```
<div class="settingsPopupWindow">
    <div>                   
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="{{getStyle(0)}}" ng-click="showTab(0)">
                <a href="">
                    First tab nav
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="{{getStyle(1)}}" ng-click="showTab(1)">
                <a href="">
                    Second tab nav
                </a>
            </li>                                       
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane {{getStyle(0)}}">                          
                First tab content
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane {{getStyle(1)}}">
                Second tab content
            </div>                                      
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I have the following code in my controller for switching tabs:

```
.......
$scope.active = 0;     

$scope.showTab = function (tabNumber) {
    $scope.active = tabNumber;
};

$scope.getStyle = function(n) {
    if (n === $scope.active) {
        return 'active';
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
.......
```

Navigation elements and tab blocks both should have `active` class if they are switched on.

In the initial state all is correct:
the first tab is switched on so `First tab nav` has `active` class
(and highlighted) and `First tab content` is displayed.

But if I click on the `Second tab nav` to switch the tabs -
only navigation element (`Second tab nav`) has the `active` class
(and `Second tab content` doesn't).

The second tab navigation element is highlighted as active
but I still see `First tab content` in the panel,
so I need to click twice on the `Second tab nav` to really switch to the second tab.

If in the initial state I click on the `Second tab nav` and after that click on the `First tab nav`,
`First tab nav` is active and highlighted but I see `Second tab content` in the pane.
So switching of the tab panels is lagging behind by one step from switching of navigation elements!
It is very surprising because the class of both navigation element and tab is got by the same function.

Help me please to switch those tabs correctly. Thank you.

**Update**

I tried to use `ng-class` instead of the `class` but it didn't help. I still have a one-click gap among switching of navigation elements and tab panels. I checked `showTab()` function, it works correctly, the number of active tab/nav switches properly. It seems that styles of the tabs are not renewing immediately after changing of active tab number, but styles of the 'navs' are still renewing immediately, and it happens regardless of using `class` or `ng-class`.

Comment: Are you using custom CSS for the `active` class, or is it bootstrap default? Please show the corresponding CSS. Perhaps it's a problem with that. Also, can you use dev tools to check whether the `active` class is applied to the proper element?

Comment: I am using bootstrap styles and `active` style works fine. But `active` style appends to navigation elements immediately after change of `active` variable in the scope and appends to tabs only one click after. I am trying to isolate my code of switching tabs to avoid influence of any other code now.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.

For your tab nav:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': active == 0}" ng-click="ShowTab(0)"><a href="">First tab nav</a></li>
<li ng-class="{'active': active == 1}"  ng-click="ShowTab(1)"><a href="">Second tab nav</a></li>
```

And for your tab content:

```
<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active': active == 0}">                          
    First tab content
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active': active == 1}">
    Second tab content
</div>
```

**EDIT: Working Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.active = 0;

  $scope.showTab = function(tabNumber) {
    $scope.active = tabNumber;
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{'active': active == 0}" ng-click="showTab(0)">
      <a href="#">First tab nav</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'active': active == 1}" ng-click="showTab(1)">
      <a href="#">Second tab nav</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active': active == 0}">
      First tab content
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active': active == 1}">
      Second tab content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried `ng-class`, but I still have the same problem, look at **Update** please.

Comment: I've added a working example to my answer. Perhaps it's something wrong with your CSS. Please post your CSS, or use dev tools to make sure that the `active` class is being applied properly when you click the corresponding tab.

Comment: Thank, your example works fine. Maybe some external code affects my styles. I am trying to dig it deeply.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) attribute.

**from the ngClass docs -**

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

In my opinion however its best not to use a function to get the class name,
but rather use the `ng-class` with the tag's scope property:

```
<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'desiredClassName': tagObject.isTagActive}">                          
    First tab content
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'desiredClassName': tagObject.isTagActive}">
    Second tab content
</div>
```

This way `tagObject` can be an object containing the tag's info.
and if its an item in a collection you can use the `ng-repeat` attr.

The `isTagActive` would be updated from any method (scope, service etc.)
and angular would immediately update the tag's `<div>` with the classes you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `ng-class`, but I still have the same problem, look at **Update** please.

Comment: @TarasSoroka Maybe its obvious but I'll ask anyway - have you updated the `class` into an `ng-class` in the tab elements as well ?

Comment: @TarasSoroka also for better answering - please provide a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/) and update the code in the question, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I added `ng-class` instead of using `{{getStyle(0)}}` in `class`. Maybe some external code affects my styles. I am trying to dig deeply my code, thanks.